# How to link pages in Webpack 5 + Pug?

Tags: webpack, hyperlink, pug

I have a basic webpack template with pug-loader. I have an entry pug file. When I develop on dev server, I need working link to another page (also written in pug). How can I do that? Should I compile pug files to html in my src directory and link html pages instead? I know browser doesn't read pug, just don't know how to set up it right

I just wrote a link to another .pug page and I always get 404. Auto creating of html files is set up for building

Answer (score 1):

Resolved myself. Needs to use url-loader with following code:

```
{
        test: /\.(html)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              // The `mimetype` and `encoding` arguments will be obtained from your options
              // The `resourcePath` argument is path to file.
              generator: (content, mimetype, encoding, resourcePath) => {
                if (/\.html$/i.test(resourcePath)) {
                  return `data:${mimetype},${content.toString()}`;
                }
                return `data:${mimetype}${
                  encoding ? `;${encoding}` : ''
                },${content.toString(encoding)}`;
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

And write links to other pug files like they paths in dist are, with .html extension